# Match array in Elastic Search instead of looping through it

Tags: javascript, json, elasticsearch

I have an array of items that need to be matched in my search. At the moment I loop through the array and perform a search for each item like this:

```
var ownerList = ['owner1', 'owner2', 'owner3'];
var searchResults = [];

for (var i = 0; i < ownerList.length; i ++ {

    var query = {
        'query': {
            'bool': {
                'must_not': {
                    'match': {'deleted': 'true'}
                },
                'must': [
                    {'match': {'owner': ownerList[i]}},
                    {'match': {'privacy': 'Public'}}
                ]
             }
         }
    };

    function doSearch(query) {
      //do search here
      searchResults.push(result);
    }
}
```

How can I put the array into my query, and perform the search without the loop?

I understand that the [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html) may work, but I have been unable to successfully implement it.

The items in the ownerList array are random strings that contain numbers, dashes and lowercase letters.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us some sample strings? are you looking for exact matches or partial matches, e.g if you have string like `solar-energy` do you want either `solar` or `energy` to match or only `solar-energy`?

Comment: Here are two example strings: 605ec41f-f32a-4f6f-a882-1a6d5379f9ab, 006e5c63-c021-4341-8d15-b7071f54b6bf. I need exact matches. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [exact matches](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html), you need to map your owner field as `not_analyzed`, Refer to [Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#custom-field-mappings) section for more info. After that you can pass your array directly to `terms filter`.

```
var ownerList = ["605ec41f-f32a-4f6f-a882-1a6d5379f9ab","006e5c63-c021-4341-8d15-b7071f54b6bf"]

var query = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "match": {
          "deleted": "true"
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "owner": ownerList
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "privacy": "Public"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you want to match *abcd-1234* to match *ABCD-1234* you need to use [keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) with [lowercase filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) for your `owner` field

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks like it will work. I am fairly new to Elastic so have just tried the new query structure without updating the mapping and am getting no hits. Is this expected? I am using [Firebase Flashlight](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) with Elastic to search my Firebase database. Can you offer any advice on how to add the mapping with this? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is expected that you wont get any results because by default ES uses `standard analyzer` and `terms filter` is looking for exact token, btw How did you create the index? did you use the `curl` command? although I have never used Firebase Flashlight, I looked at the project and I guess It is for searching only, am I right?

Comment: Yes I think only searching. If I understand your question correctly, I configured the index in the paths array on line 63 of the [config.js](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight/blob/master/config.js#L63) file in the Flashlight app. Does that look correct? Thanks again

Comment: I tried this: `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/firebase -d '
{
    "mappings": {
        "post": {
          "owner": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
'` but got `{"error":"IndexAlreadyExistsException[[firebase] already exists]","status":400}`.

Comment: you were very close. First you have to delete the index, run `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/firebase/'` , then create a new index like this `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/firebase/' -d '{"mappings":{"post":{"properties":{"owner":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyzed"}}}}}'` . [This](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html) is the documentation.

Comment: After deleting the index and then adding it with the new mapping as suggested, I got `{"error":"MapperParsingException[mapping [post]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Wrong value for index [not_analyzed] for field [owner]]; ","status":400}`

Comment: I am running ES version 0.90.7

Comment: ES 0.90.7 is so old friend, try this `curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/firebase/post/_mapping' -d '{"post":{"properties":{"owner":{"type":"string","index":"not_analyz‌​ed"}}}}'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100918/discussion-between-chintanshah25-and-karlp).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR for the different values (`should` section).
Something like that:

```
var ownerCondition = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ownerList.length; i ++ {
    ownerCondition.push( "{'match': {'owner': " + ownerList[i] + "}}" );
};

var query = {
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must_not': {
                'match': {'deleted': 'true'}
            },
            'should': ownerCondition,
            'must': [
                {'match': {'privacy': 'Public'}}
            ]
         }
     }
};
```